# Wifi signals can be detected but cannot connect

Tags: wireless

I just installed Ubuntu on HP Pavillion 350 laptop. Here is the output of my wireless-info file:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/16412598/

The Wifi signals can be detected but the computer does not connect. Your help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Seif